# What is HTMLCleaner in android

Tags: android, html

Can anyone tell me what Html Cleaner is and for which purpose it is used?

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 3):

hi Refer this answer from  this site http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/,

> HtmlCleaner is **open-source** HTML
>   parser written in Java. HTML found on
>   Web is usually dirty, ill-formed and
>   unsuitable for further processing. For
>   any serious consumption of such
>   documents, it is necessary to first
>   clean up the mess and bring the order
>   to tags, attributes and ordinary text.
>   For the given HTML document,
>   HtmlCleaner reorders individual
>   elements and produces well-formed XML.
>   By default, it follows similar rules
>   that the most of web browsers use in
>   order to create Document Object Model.
>   However, user may provide custom tag
>   and rule set for tag filtering and
>   balancing.

For Instance, Consider the following example..........,

```
<table id=table1 cellspacing=2px
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <td><a href=index.html>1 -> Home Page</a>
    <td><a href=intro.html>2 -> Introduction</a>


    After putting it through HtmlCleaner, XML similar to the following is coming out: 
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <html>
       <head />
       <body>
          <h1>CONTENT</h1>
          <table id="table1" cellspacing="2px">
             <tbody>
                <tr>
                   <td>
                      <a href="index.html">1 -&gt; Home Page</a>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <a href="intro.html">2 -&gt; Introduction</a>
                   </td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
          </table>
       </body>
    </html>
```

And refer this site for how to use htmlCleaner , http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/using-xpath-and-html-cleaner-to-parse-html-xml/

Answer (score 2):

HTML Cleaner is a library to "clean" as it's name says and convert bad-formed HTML to XHTML in order to be able to parse it using an XML parser.